# STL <map> allows duplicate pairs?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have written the following code and was surprised at the output. I heard that `<map>` avoids collision of keys, but here it appears to allow insertion of duplicate pairs.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<string,char> namemap;
    namemap["yogi"]='c';

    namemap.insert(pair<string,char>("yogendra",'a'));
    namemap.insert(pair<string,char>("yogendra",'b'));

    cout<<namemap["yogendra"]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code outputs `a`.  You can run it on [C++ Shell](http://cpp.sh/5u5k).

Does avoiding collision means that we cannot enter multiple pairs with same key?

Comment: What behavior did you expect? An exception? Overwriting the first value with the second? Ignoring the second value? A compiler error?

Comment: It is clearly explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert)

Comment: @MatthieuM. Too right. Although for beginners sometimes it is a matter of finding the right manual.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The second `insert` with the same key is a no-op. It simply returns an iterator pointing to the existing element.

`std::map::insert()` has a return value, which you should check.

It is of type `std::pair<iterator,bool>`. The second element of the pair tells you whether the element has been inserted, or whether there was already an existing entry with the same key.

```
cout << namemap.insert(pair<string,char>("yogendra",'a')).second << endl;
cout << namemap.insert(pair<string,char>("yogendra",'b')).second << endl;
```

Answer (score 20):

STL map does not allow same Keys to be used. You may want to go for multi-map for that.

Answer (score 6):

a map will not throw any compile/run time error while inserting value using duplicate key. but while inserting, using the duplicate key it will not insert a new value, it will return the same exiting value only. it will not overwrite.
but in the below case it will be overwritten.

```
map<char,int> m1;
m1.insert(pair <char, int> ('a', 40));
m1['a']=50;
cout << "a => " << m1.find('a')->second << '\n';
```

The result will be 50.

below example, it will not overwrite.

```
map<char,int> m1;
m1.insert(pair <char, int> ('a', 40));
m1.insert(pair <char, int> ('a', 50));
cout << "a => " << m1.find('a')->second << '\n';
```

Result will be 40.

Remember map size 1 here for both the cases.

```
cout< "size =  " << m1.size() << '\n';
```

it will be 1 in both cases.

Comment: What information does this add over answers posted more than six years ago?

Comment: duplicate answer. No need to post it for the sake of getting kudos.